# SAML: service provider specific login page customization in openam

Tags: saml-2.0, openam

I am looking for a way to customize the SSO (using SAML) login page in openam for each service provider. Tried searching the web but could not find a way to do the same. looking at Login.jsp, there is view bean being used but that does seems to have any public methods to identify the SP in context.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken the Login.jsp should have access to the spEntityID request parameter, which should tell you exactly which SP is involved in the authentication process.